# Maximum number of $\mathbb{R}^3$ vectors that have negative dot products?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

What is the maximum number of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that all have negative dot products (ie $\forall v,w: v \cdot w < 0$) ?  What is one example of such a set of vectors?  How do you know that is the maximum number?

More generally, what is the maximum number (as a function of $n$) of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that have all negative dot products?

Comment: See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31436/largest-number-of-vectors-with-pairwise-negative-dot-product).